# How to make a join query in Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can i effectively perform a join query to select the chatId from the "**users**" node, and with that chatId get the message items from the "**chats**" table.

Sample JSON: (1, 2, 134 and 155 are random user id's)

```
{
  "chats" : {
    "-KD3x3Y16YdQHWSBXR5K" : {
      "-KD3x3Y5zew00h29ZG55" : {
        "text" : "hello",
        "timestamp" : "1458224515",
        "userId" : 1
      },
      "-KD3x4B1rmbAKTVsOOYn" : {
        "text" : "test",
        "timestamp" : "1458224517",
        "userId" : 1
      }
    },
    "-KD3xLNuLU6IxB85u41S" : {
      "-KD3xLNv32FzDuqlXR1V" : {
        "text" : "bla",
        "timestamp" : "1458224588",
        "userId" : 134
      }
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "1" : {
      "2" : {
        "chatId" : "-KD3x3Y16YdQHWSBXR5K"
      }
    },
    "134" : {
      "155" : {
        "chatId" : "-KD3xLNuLU6IxB85u41S"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-10-01-queries-part-one.html#join

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Image has been replaced with the actual JSON. since you are a developer on the Firebase team, can you help me with an answer?

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Comment: I made it work using double queries. First get the chatId from the users table using one query and use that chatId in the second query to get the message items. Can this be done in a better way? I feel like i'm doing it wrong with 2 select statements!

Comment: I appreciate the tutorial you have shared whereby you showed the solution being implemented using Javascript. Can you please post an example for Android/Java?

Comment: Would love to see your updated answer if you ever figured it out!

Comment: @MobileMon I ended up using another solution for this specific project. But you can check `Pipiks` comment above that includes a link to show how to do joins in Firebase